# Hot spot problem in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless, ufw

I am using a Ubuntu 22.04 machine. I want to share my Ethernet data to my mobile via
Hot spot. But I can't connect to it via mobile.I searched for solution and tried by disabling the firewall. Then it worked, but I guess it is dangerous. Is there any other option so that I can use hot spot and don't need to disable the firewall?

Comment: Try [linux-wifi-hotspot](https://github.com/lakinduakash/linux-wifi-hotspot)